# Sort performance issue in django psql query

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql

I'm using django and PostgreSQL and I'm having big performance problems with this query that takes up to 8-10 seconds.

I have a model "Publication" on which Instagram publications are stored. I'm trying to get the publications within a  certain city, but the relationship is not very direct, so the query is:

```
instagram_publications = Publication.objects.filter(location__spot__city__name=location)
```

So in the models we have: Publication [FK]-> Location [FK] -> Spot [FK] -> City. All this models inherit from TimeStampedModel also.

And as the search is by city name, I have added an index in City.name setting db_index=True but nothing changed.

I'm analyzing this query calling explain, and I see big cost related to sort. It seems that it sorts the rows by creation date and last modification date that are fields inherited from TimestampedModel, and I think that is unnecessary such sort, but I'm not sure about how to avoid it.

```
[PERFORMANCE ANALYSIS]> City filter Instagram
Sort  (cost=256874.73..257992.17 rows=446975 width=233) (actual time=294.240..343.831 rows=290637 loops=1)
  Sort Key: instanalysis_publication.modified DESC, instanalysis_publication.created DESC
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 60400kB
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..114091.50 rows=446975 width=233) (actual time=0.055..110.515 rows=290637 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..516.27 rows=2767 width=4) (actual time=0.044..3.145 rows=3374 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..39.28 rows=504 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.323 rows=829 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on instanalysis_city  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((name)::text = 'Durban'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 7
                    ->  Index Scan using instanalysis_spot_c7141997 on instanalysis_spot  (cost=0.28..33.14 rows=504 width=8) (actual time=0.024..0.208 rows=829 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (city_id = instanalysis_city.id)
              ->  Index Scan using instanalysis_instagramlocation_e72b53d4 on instanalysis_instagramlocation  (cost=0.29..0.89 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=4 loops=829)
                    Index Cond: (spot_id = instanalysis_spot.id)
        ->  Index Scan using instanalysis_publication_e274a5da on instanalysis_publication  (cost=0.43..36.20 rows=485 width=233) (actual time=0.002..0.019 rows=86 loops=3374)
              Index Cond: (location_id = instanalysis_instagramlocation.id)
Planning time: 0.809 ms
Execution time: 355.928 ms
```

It seems that the sorting is being made on disc also, and I guess that is cause there are thousands of rows, so maybe can't be done in memory.

The TimeStampedModel class comes from django_extras package and ordering is defined inside Meta:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    """ TimeStampedModel
    An abstract base class model that provides self-managed "created" and
    "modified" fields.
    """
    created = CreationDateTimeField(_('created'))
    modified = ModificationDateTimeField(_('modified'))

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.update_modified = kwargs.pop('update_modified', getattr(self, 'update_modified', True))
        super(TimeStampedModel, self).save(**kwargs)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'modified'
        ordering = ('-modified', '-created',)
        abstract = True
```

Is there a way to improve it or maybe avoid the sorting step?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use a pagination and order by publication id.

Comment: Thanks @L.Xiao, I've tried doing  Publication.objects.filter(location__spot__city__name=location).order_by('id') but i don't see anychanges, when i run explain analyze it still trying to sort by fields instanalysis_publication.modified and  instanalysis_publication.created. I think that is unnecessary that sort, but it's defined in TimeStampedModel class so I don't know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way to avoid sorting, overriding the class Meta in Publication model and just setting ordering = None.

```
class Meta:
    #  Important: Override ordering inherited from TimeStampedModel to improve performance
    ordering = None
```

Now I don't see the cost of that sorting step, but when I run it and measure the time iseems to be taking the same time than before, regardless on what EXPLAIN ANALIZE says.

```
[PERFORMANCE ANALYSIS]> City filter Instagram
Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..110920.28 rows=452607 width=233) (actual time=0.069..96.667 rows=290637 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..516.27 rows=2767 width=4) (actual time=0.056..2.476 rows=3374 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..39.28 rows=504 width=4) (actual time=0.047..0.254 rows=829 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on instanalysis_city  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((name)::text = 'Durban'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 7
              ->  Index Scan using instanalysis_spot_c7141997 on instanalysis_spot  (cost=0.28..33.14 rows=504 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.170 rows=829 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (city_id = instanalysis_city.id)
        ->  Index Scan using instanalysis_instagramlocation_e72b53d4 on instanalysis_instagramlocation  (cost=0.29..0.89 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=4 loops=829)
              Index Cond: (spot_id = instanalysis_spot.id)
  ->  Index Scan using instanalysis_publication_e274a5da on instanalysis_publication  (cost=0.43..34.99 rows=491 width=233) (actual time=0.002..0.016 rows=86 loops=3374)
        Index Cond: (location_id = instanalysis_instagramlocation.id)
Planning time: 1.385 ms
Execution time: 103.446 ms
```